# MySQL function to find delimiter occurrences error

Tags: mysql, sql, function, mysql-5.7

I have the below function. Upon execution, it says 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version.' Please help me find the issue.
MySQL - 5.7

```
CREATE FUNCTION count_Occurrence(str varchar(1000),x varchar(20)) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
SET @cn:=0;
WHILE (INSTR(str,x) <> 0) DO
    SET @cn=@cn+1;
    REPLACE(str,SUBSTRING(str,0,INSTR(str,x)),"");
END WHILE;
RETURN @cn;
END
```

```
Test input:  str= 'abc;sdifh;1231;hsjh;wque' x=';'
Output: 4
```

Comment: Is that the entire error message? ... seems to be missing a little more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you prefer to stay closer to your original code, a couple of minor corrections are needed.

1. The `SUBSTRING` needs 1 as the second parameter, not 0.
2. The `REPLACE` returns the string after modifying, so need to add `SET str =`  before the REPLACE to get the updated string as the loop processes.

Here's the code with those changes applied:

```
CREATE FUNCTION count_Occurrence(str varchar(1000),x varchar(20)) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    SET  @cn = 0;
    WHILE (INSTR(str,x) <> 0) DO
        SET @cn = @cn + 1;
        SET str = REPLACE(str,SUBSTRING(str,1,INSTR(str,x)),"");
    END WHILE;
    RETURN @cn;
END
```

Then running a test query:

```
SELECT count_Occurrence('abc;sdifh;1231;hsjh;wque', ';') AS found;
```

Gives:
[image]

See this [example DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d08962fe65a901a5cc953a5d763214bd) with the function and the query to check. In the first block after the version output shows that 0 with the SUBSTRING retrieves nothing.

Answer (score 2):

How about an alternative implementation, like this one:

```
(CHAR_LENGTH(str) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(str, x, ''))) / CHAR_LENGTH(x)
```

To me at least, that implementation looks both simpler and more performant.

---

Now, let's break it down and explain how the above works.

The expression can be seen as:

```
(A - B) / C
```

where:

```
A = CHAR_LENGTH(str)
B = CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(str, x, ''))
C = CHAR_LENGTH(x)
```

Let me give you an example, where:

```
str = 'Some fuXYnny XYstrXYing'
x = 'XY'
```

Then we will have:

```
A = 23
B = 17   // comes from CHAR_LENGTH('Some funny string')
C = 2
```

And the result would be

```
(23-17)/2 = 6/2 = 3
```

Comment: It worked but I did not understand the exact logic. Could you please explain ??

Comment: @maddy_novice I updated my answer with a detailed explanation.